# Get count of people who answered a question in a survey

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the total amount of people who answered a question in a survey, so the survey_id and survey_question_id has to match a value and then I have to be able to separate the user_id so that it counts only the ones that are different, some questions can have multiple answers from the same person. How can I do this?

This is the table schema from the table where I want to get this info

```
Schema::create('survey_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('survey_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('survey_question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('answer');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('survey_id')->references('id')->on('surveys');
            $table->foreign('survey_question_id')->references('id')->on('survey_questions');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

I was thinking something like this, this returns 1 when it should return a 7. I'm not sure why or how to fix it. If I remove the `groupBy` and `count` then I get a 7, but that won't work will all the questions because some of the question are multiple choice and can have 15 answers make by only 5 people por example. The final idea for this is to show a report with the percent or people who picked each answer and for that I need the total, in my code I already have the amount of answers for each option.

```
$total = SurveyAnswer::where('survey_id', $survey->id)->where('survey_question_id', $question->id)
                    ->groupBy('user_id')->count();
```

Comment: If you group by user id you're going to get one row per user who gave that answer. `count()` will count how many times each user gave that answer, which is going to be 1 . If you don't use `groupBy` you'll probably get what you want which is the number of users who gave that specific answer

Comment: @apokryfos what I want is the amount of different users who answered the question independent of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number of distinct users who answered a given question you can try:

```
$total = SurveyAnswer::where('survey_id', $survey->id)
              ->where('survey_question_id', $question->id)
              ->selectRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as count')
              ->value('count');
```

This should return how many distinct users answered that question, regardless how many times

Comment: I think your answer's effect is as same as the post `groupBy(user_id)`

Comment: @TsaiKoga `groupBy(user_id)` will indeed result in distinct user ids **but** then doing `COUNT` will affect each user_id instead of counting all of them. If `group by` is to be used then it need to be in a nested query with the outer query doing the `count` in order to get the same effect

Comment: yes, u r right. my mistake. I am not unaware of that.